# JPype won't compile properly

Tags: python, compilation, jvm, jpype

So I am having trouble compiling a very simple python script using [JPype](http://jpype.sourceforge.net/).

My code goes like:

```py
from jpype import *
startJVM(getDefaultJVMPath(), "-ea")
java.lang.System.out.println("hello world")
shutdownJVM()
```

and when I run it I receive an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 2, in
<module>
    startJVM(getDefaultJVMPath(), "-ea")   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/jpype/_core.py", line 44, in startJVM
    _jpype.startup(jvm, tuple(args), True) RuntimeError: Unable to load DLL [/usr/java/jre1.5.0_05/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so], error =
/usr/java/jre1.5.0_05/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so: cannot open shared
object file: No such file or directory at
src/native/common/include/jp_platform_linux.h:45
```

I'm stuck and I really need help. Thanks!

Comment: The error message is "no such file or directory". Can you confirm the existence of the file "/usr/java/jre1.5.0_05/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so" ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem

```
RuntimeError: Unable to load DLL [/usr/java/jre1.5.0_05/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so], error = /usr/java/jre1.5.0_05/lib/i386/client/libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at src/native/common/include/jp_platform_linux.h:45
```

In my case wrong JAVA_HOME path was set

/profile/etc

```
export JAVA_HOME
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64
PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

The work around is to define the full path directly in the call to the JVM:

```
from jpype import *
startJVM('/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib', "-ea", "-Djava.class.path=/tmp/Jpype/sample")
java.lang.System.out.println("Hello World!!")
shutdownJVM()
```

Original text:

> Similar issues when trying to run JPype on MacOS El Capitan. I could
>   not figure out how to coax the _darwin.py code finding the correct JVM
>   location, despite the JAVA_HOME system variable being set properly.

*Caveat cursor*, trying to run the above code in the Spyder IPython console did not produce any output, but the normal Console would.